# Electrostatic Potential at Axis (Containing Diameter) of Uniformly Charged Non Conducting Semi-Circular Ring

Tags: electrostatics

[image]

Here we have a Uniformly Charged Non-Conducting Semi-Circular Ring of Radius R and Charge Q.

Its Diameter is placed on the X-Axis (The Black Line).

The potential at the Center of the Ring is
$$V_c=\frac{kQ}{R}$$

But let us say we have a point on the X-Axis $(u,0)$ and let the center be Origin.

As long as $-R\leq u \leq R$ which is a point on the diameter of the ring.

What will be the potential?

Using some dubious integration which I am not sure of I got that the answer will be same as Center.

Here is the rough Graph which I am getting for potential.

Potential remains constant for any point on the diameter. If you could help me prove or disprove this as I am not sure.

[image]

Although as $R \to 0$, the graph starts resembling more of that of a point charge, which is expected behavior as the Semi Circular Ring will indeed become a point charge.

[image]